# Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 C++ 64-bit debug std::_Container_base_secure linker error

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-studio-2013

i just encountered in  an Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 64bit C++ debug project, the following linker errors:

```
Error   307 error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __cdecl std::_Container_base_secure::~_Container_base_secure(void)" (__imp_??1_Container_base_secure@std@@QEAA@XZ) C:\DevelopmentX64_old\SmartCamXi_Hybrid\Recorder\CameraControlLib64\h264_dec.lib(umc_h264_nal_spl.obj)  CameraControlLib64
Error   308 error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __cdecl std::_Container_base_secure::~_Container_base_secure(void)" (__imp_??1_Container_base_secure@std@@QEAA@XZ) C:\DevelopmentX64_old\SmartCamXi_Hybrid\Recorder\CameraControlLib64\core_umc.lib(umc_default_frame_allocator.obj)   CameraControlLib64
Error   309 error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __cdecl std::_Container_base_secure::~_Container_base_secure(void)" (__imp_??1_Container_base_secure@std@@QEAA@XZ) C:\DevelopmentX64_old\SmartCamXi_Hybrid\Recorder\CameraControlLib64\h264_dec.lib(umc_h264_task_supplier.obj)    CameraControlLib64
Error   310 error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __cdecl std::_Container_base_secure::~_Container_base_secure(void)" (__imp_??1_Container_base_secure@std@@QEAA@XZ) C:\DevelopmentX64_old\SmartCamXi_Hybrid\Recorder\CameraControlLib64\h264_dec.lib(umc_h264_frame.obj)    CameraControlLib64
Error   311 error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __cdecl std::_Container_base_secure::~_Container_base_secure(void)" (__imp_??1_Container_base_secure@std@@QEAA@XZ) C:\DevelopmentX64_old\SmartCamXi_Hybrid\Recorder\CameraControlLib64\h264_dec.lib(umc_h264_thread.obj)   CameraControlLib64
Error   312 error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __cdecl std::_Container_base_secure::~_Container_base_secure(void)" (__imp_??1_Container_base_secure@std@@QEAA@XZ) C:\DevelopmentX64_old\SmartCamXi_Hybrid\Recorder\CameraControlLib64\h264_dec.lib(umc_h264_task_broker.obj)  CameraControlLib64
Error   313 error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: void __cdecl std::_Container_base_secure::_Orphan_all(void)const " (__imp_?_Orphan_all@_Container_base_secure@std@@QEBAXXZ)    C:\DevelopmentX64_old\SmartCamXi_Hybrid\Recorder\CameraControlLib64\core_umc.lib(umc_default_frame_allocator.obj)   CameraControlLib64
Error   314 error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: void __cdecl std::_Container_base_secure::_Orphan_all(void)const " (__imp_?_Orphan_all@_Container_base_secure@std@@QEBAXXZ)    C:\DevelopmentX64_old\SmartCamXi_Hybrid\Recorder\CameraControlLib64\h264_dec.lib(umc_h264_task_supplier.obj)    CameraControlLib64
Error   315 error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: void __cdecl std::_Container_base_secure::_Orphan_all(void)const " (__imp_?_Orphan_all@_Container_base_secure@std@@QEBAXXZ)    C:\DevelopmentX64_old\SmartCamXi_Hybrid\Recorder\CameraControlLib64\h264_dec.lib(umc_h264_thread.obj)   CameraControlLib64
Error   316 error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: void __cdecl std::_Container_base_secure::_Orphan_all(void)const " (__imp_?_Orphan_all@_Container_base_secure@std@@QEBAXXZ)    C:\DevelopmentX64_old\SmartCamXi_Hybrid\Recorder\CameraControlLib64\h264_dec.lib(umc_h264_task_broker.obj)  CameraControlLib64
Error   317 error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: void __cdecl std::_Container_base_secure::_Orphan_all(void)const " (__imp_?_Orphan_all@_Container_base_secure@std@@QEBAXXZ)    C:\DevelopmentX64_old\SmartCamXi_Hybrid\Recorder\CameraControlLib64\h264_dec.lib(umc_h264_nal_spl.obj)  CameraControlLib64
Error   318 error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __cdecl std::_Container_base_secure::_Container_base_secure(void)" (__imp_??0_Container_base_secure@std@@QEAA@XZ)  C:\DevelopmentX64_old\SmartCamXi_Hybrid\Recorder\CameraControlLib64\h264_dec.lib(umc_h264_nal_spl.obj)  CameraControlLib64
Error   319 error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __cdecl std::_Container_base_secure::_Container_base_secure(void)" (__imp_??0_Container_base_secure@std@@QEAA@XZ)  C:\DevelopmentX64_old\SmartCamXi_Hybrid\Recorder\CameraControlLib64\core_umc.lib(umc_default_frame_allocator.obj)   CameraControlLib64
Error   320 error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __cdecl std::_Container_base_secure::_Container_base_secure(void)" (__imp_??0_Container_base_secure@std@@QEAA@XZ)  C:\DevelopmentX64_old\SmartCamXi_Hybrid\Recorder\CameraControlLib64\h264_dec.lib(umc_h264_task_supplier.obj)    CameraControlLib64
Error   321 error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __cdecl std::_Container_base_secure::_Container_base_secure(void)" (__imp_??0_Container_base_secure@std@@QEAA@XZ)  C:\DevelopmentX64_old\SmartCamXi_Hybrid\Recorder\CameraControlLib64\h264_dec.lib(umc_h264_frame.obj)    CameraControlLib64
Error   322 error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __cdecl std::_Container_base_secure::_Container_base_secure(void)" (__imp_??0_Container_base_secure@std@@QEAA@XZ)  C:\DevelopmentX64_old\SmartCamXi_Hybrid\Recorder\CameraControlLib64\h264_dec.lib(umc_h264_thread.obj)   CameraControlLib64
Error   323 error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __cdecl std::_Container_base_secure::_Container_base_secure(void)" (__imp_??0_Container_base_secure@std@@QEAA@XZ)  C:\DevelopmentX64_old\SmartCamXi_Hybrid\Recorder\CameraControlLib64\h264_dec.lib(umc_h264_task_broker.obj)  CameraControlLib64
```

Upon research, I could not find anything specific to this problem.Here are the linker settings:

```
AdditionalDependencies: libcurl.lib;comsuppw.lib;winhttp.lib;Ws2_32.lib;strmiids.lib;vfw32.lib;ippac.lib;ippcc.lib;ippch.lib;ippcore.lib;ippcv.lib;ippdc.lib;ippdi.lib;ippgen.lib;ippi.lib;ippj.lib;ippm.lib;ippr.lib;ipps.lib;ippsc.lib;ippvc.lib;ippvm.lib;libiomp5md.lib;aac_common.lib;aac_dec.lib;aac_enc.lib;ac3_dec.lib;application_common.lib;avi_spl.lib;codec_common.lib;common_cc.lib;common_me.lib;common_sa.lib;container_common.lib;core_umc.lib;h264_dec.lib;h264_enc.lib;io_umc.lib;media_buffers.lib;mjpeg_dec.lib;mp3_common.lib;mp3_dec.lib;mp3_enc.lib;mpeg2_dec.lib;mpeg2_enc.lib;mpeg2_mux.lib;mpeg2_spl.lib;mpeg4_dec.lib;mpeg4_enc.lib;mpeg4_mux.lib;mpeg4_spl.lib;renders_audio.lib;renders_video.lib;vc1_common.lib;vc1_dec.lib;vc1_enc.lib;vc1_spl.lib;vm.lib;vm_plus.lib;setupapi.lib;pdh.lib;winmm.lib;ClickItliveMedia.lib;ClickItBasicUsageEnvironment.lib;libgroupsock.lib;libUsageEnvironment.lib;%(AdditionalDependencies)
```

here are the C/C++ Compiler settings:

```
Preprocessor Definitions:
WIN64;_WIN64;_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS;_CRT_NON_CONFORMING_SWPRINTFS;NDEBUG;_WINDOWS;WINDOWS;_USRDLL;CAMERACONTROLLIB_EXPORTS;%(PreprocessorDefinitions)
```

Any help in resolving this is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You should show the code you are compiling for which you are getting these link errors.

Comment: I only read the first few error messages. It looks like you are attempting to import a DLL. Given that you are using VS2013, and the directory this stuff is in is "C:\DevelopmentX64_old" is there a possibility the DLL was built with a different version of Visual Studio and the name-mangling is not correct for VS2013? So it is looking for functions that don't exist (or are named differently) in the .lib that corresponds to that dll?

Comment: I agree. Most likely this problem happens because you are trying to compile your project with libs, assembled for the different STL version.

Comment: Formatting is greatly appreciated. You've been here for four and a half years! C'mon!

Comment: @RyanP, Thank you for your excellent comment.

Comment: @Ari0nhh, Thank you for yor great comment.

Comment: @Lightness Races in Orbit, I forgot to format my question in the haste to find an answer for my problem.

Comment: @Frank np, did you get it figured out?

Comment: @Ryanp, The h264_dec.lib we were using is a 32-bit version rather than a 64-bit version, Thank you for your help.

Comment: @RyanP, The h264_dec.lib we were using was compiled and linked as a 32-bit version rather than a 64-bit version, H264 is a video codec stream type. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

May be you are trying to import a DLL but vs2013 is unable to find it in the specified path.
If not then try closing and restarting your machine. May be it will help. (This has helped me in some windows forms application)

Comment: Thank you for your help. I am about to vote for your answer.